# react.js rendering react components on client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using node.js with react.js as my templating library. I am able to render my components on server side by using node's res.render(..), but I want to make my components dynamic by rendering them on client side using react.js and calling the onclick handlers. I have my components defined in .jsx format. How can I interact with the browser in client side and render my react components dynamically?

Comment: I am doing this.  Instead of using react as just a templating library (like the Hapi react plugin) I went down the route of creating a proper Universal React configuration.  It's quite complicated to set up initially but it's amazing when you get going.  Check out this example: https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have your code transpiled and bundled, then you can insert it in a script tag just like any other script. One popular option is webpack; another is the use of Browserify with babelify in a gulp task.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using it with ES6 class syntax using babel js. I have created a sample component [here](https://jsbin.com/gusole/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

You can also use [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) which gives you all the setup pre-loaded. A good place to start would be Facebook's react [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/)